# PDO pulls in columns into my object that are not defined in my class

Tags: php, pdo

So I define a class with a few predefined properties.

```
class User
{
    public $id;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
}
```

Then I query the database using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` to fetch the result into an object of the above mentioned `User` class.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');

foreach($users as $user)
{
    print_r($user);
}
```

But now when I iterate over the resulting `User` object it contains other properties that I did not define in my `User` class.

```
User Object
(
    [id] => 1
    [firstName] => Bruce
    [lastName] => Wayne
    [city] => Gotham
    [residence] => Batcave
    ...
)
```

So...

- Why is it putting in new properties that I did not define?
- How can I prevent it from creating its own properties?
- Am I doing something wrong?
- What is the purpose of even making my own class (model) and declaring properties if its just going to put whatever it wants in there anyway?

Comment: Just out of idle curiousity, could you define one of those variables as private and see if PDO throws an error or just don't set the data? I'm not suggesting this as a solution because then you'd be forbidding a specific column to be loaded forever, which is not good, but I was curious.

Comment: Then it still writes values to it, but in `print_r` the column gets suffixed with `:user:private`, e.g. `[firstName:user:private] => Bruce`.

Comment: This comment doesn't address the issue of adding non-predefined properties into your object, but as for your last question, I think you don't really get much out of using FETCH_CLASS unless the class you are fetching into has some methods rather than just properties. If the object is just a data holder and doesn't really do anything you might as well just use FETCH_OBJ, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

```
FETCH_CLASS
```

is designed to **mapping the columns of the result set to named properties in the class.**

If you only want some properties, alter your query and only take those you need, i.e.

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName FROM users
```

Comment: Is there any other way? Because with tables with many columns where I want almost all of the columns I would have to type a really long comma-separated string there. Also what is the point of declaring a class with predefined properties at all if it is going to write all columns into the object anyway?

Comment: Well in that case you would need to the mapping manually. Take the values of the result set and assign it one-by-one to your class. Or write some method that does that for you.

Comment: Then I see no purpose as to why to define a class with predefined properties or why to use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` over `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Comment: If you only need to map the query to a object with the properties, FETCH_OBJ works just fine for that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as explaining why `FETCH_CLASS` works that way, I really can't be much help. But that is how it works, and you aren't doing anything wrong. If you want to be able to just use `SELECT * ...` and fetch the results into objects filling only their defined properties, I don't think there is any built-in part of PDO that will do that. One way to achieve this would be to create a constructor for your object that would initialize it using values from an array, like this.

```
class User
{
    public $id;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;

    function __construct($record) {
        foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($record[$key])) $this->$key = $record[$key];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use `FETCH_ASSOC` instead, and create your objects with the resulting arrays.

```
while ($record = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, 'User')) {
    $users[] = new User($record);
}
```

I do not know if there would be any added value from using this approach rather than just specifying which columns you want in your query. You would basically just be transferring the work of specifying a potentially long list of columns from the query into the object.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this is to check in the constructor which vars are defined by the class:

```
foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $objVar => $val) {
    $classKeys = array_keys(get_class_vars(self::class));
    foreach(get_object_vars($this) as $objVar => $val) {
        if (!in_array($objVar, $classKeys)) {
            $this->$objVar = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You still end up with the extra properties on the class, but they are all set to null.  I used a trait to make this function available in several classes, and it worked well.  You can then make it optional in the constructor using a parameter on the setFetchMode call:

```
$db->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User', [User::CLEAN]);
```

Then you constructor can look something like this:

```
public function __construct($type = null) {
    if ($type == self::CLEAN) {
        $this->clean();
    }
}
```

This obviously can't be used with PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE.